# How to perform onDelete with Section item inside ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

In abolutely new project I have this code for testing:

```
extension Int: Identifiable {
    
    public var id: UUID { UUID() }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let data: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(data) {
                Section(header: Text("\($0)")) {
                    ForEach(data) {
                        Text("\($0)")
                    }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                        print("Delete \(indexSet)")
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case there is no such action as swipe to delete. By default you can swipe and see delete button right after you type onDelete to ForEach. But when you place Section in ForEach this isn't happening.
It will appear when I remove Section. Even if I have ForEach in ForEach in ForEach it still works. But not with Section in it – why?

Xcode 12.4
Swift 5

Answer (score 0):

You just need to provide an array of arrays with the rows for each section:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data: [[Int]] = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(data.indices, id: \.self) { section in
                Section(header: Text("\(section+1)")) {
                    ForEach(data[section], id: \.self) { row in
                        Text("\(row)")
                    }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                        data[section].remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```